# Android ListView Live Updating

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

I have a ListView in a ListActivity that's bound to some data.  I have a content provider that's providing the data.

The ListActivity gets the data by querying a content resolver:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://my.provider.DocumentProvider/mystuff");
contentCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

So now the activity has the cursor.  It creates an adapter and attaches it to the list:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new DocumentListCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main_row_layout, contentCursor, new String[] { "titleColumn" }, new int[] { titleColumnIndex  });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This works fine; the list shows the data in the cursor.

But now the content provider has new data.  I want the list to update to show the new data.

The examples I've seen involve a call to the adapter's notifyDataSetChanged, but it seems to me that this breaks the separation between the content provider and the list, which is consuming the content.

Does the content provider need to know what adapters are attached to the cursor so it can call their notifyDataSetChanged method?  Or is there a better way that doesn't see these two things coupled this way.

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean%29 ?

Comment: I did try registering with registerContentObserver, but didn't see a change come in when the cursor changed.  Should that work?

Comment: same as slukian, plus you may need `contentCursor.setNotificationUri(cr, uri);`

Comment: Who calls contentResolver.notifyChange()?  The content provider wouldn't have access to call that, would it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html

In a nutshell, the provider calls notifyChange to indicate that the content at the URI has changed:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

And the ListActivity calls setNotificationUri on the cursor to register that it's interested in receiving notification of changes:

```
contentCursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

(Thanks njzk2 for pointing me in the right direction).

Comment: Hi, I am working on a similar problem. I have a custom BaseAdapter and I pass a Cursor obtained from the Content Provider to the Adapter. Now based on your Q & A. If I may ask, from documentation `setNotificationUri` **Notifies the listener attached to the Resolver**. How are using this to update the Listview? Are you not using ContentObserver?

Comment: Is the URI just a made-up value?  How do I know my URI isn't accidentally the same as some other app's URI?

Comment: You'd use your reverse-DNS identifier at the start of the URI.  com.mycompany.MyURI or something like that.  That way, as long as you own the mycompany.com domain there will be no accidental conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

asuming that ContentProvider is yours you should add `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` in your `query` implementation of CP(before you return cursor) and `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` in `update`, `insert`, `delete` ... `SimpleCursorAdapter` which is prolly base of your `DocumentListCursorAdapter` should take care about refreshing listview.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want to update list as per data changed.
For that just try this :
when you get new cursor then just put this code instead set new adapter to list..

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

and

```
listview.invalidate()
```

Comment: How do I know when to get a new cursor?  The data has changed (for example, because of some network activity - new data received) and the Content Provider is aware that the data has changed.  What does the content provider do to get the notification through to the ListActivity?  

It's easy enough to solve this if you assume the provider and the list are in the same app, but what if the content provider is connected to a list in a different process?  What does the content provider do to communicate the change across to where the list is?

Comment: Do we need to do the both or `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` will update the Listview?